# Inner shadow for image's cell in collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view and i want to have an inner shadow when i select a cell . I was trying this :

```
UICollectionViewCell  *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
        recipeImageView.frame=CGRectMake(recipeImageView.frame.origin.x, recipeImageView.frame.origin.y, 120, 120);
        backgroundImage= (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
        backgroundImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"layout-2015-03-05-093344.png"];
```

but even if my image is with transparency background , the first image is not visible.

Comment: I'd suggest a custom `UICollectionViewCell` with the overwrite of `setSelected:`.

Comment: Thanks . Now it ' s working